# Click is happening some other place on Cart ICON in MSITE from appium code - Chrome browser

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, appium, appium-android

I am trying to click on cart icon on top right corner from Appium in chrome browser mobile.

**Code to click :**

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/viewcart']")).click();`

> URL : https://www.2gud.com/?cmpid=2G108229

*Note: Please open this URL in mobile device and verify.*

> Error : Code is clicking somewhere else on mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

This is working. Checked in Android 7.1 emulator

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/rv/viewcart']")).click();
```

[image]

```
public class Demo {

    public static WebDriver driver = null;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws  InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Launching the chrome driver  ");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","src\\test\\resources\\drivers\\chromedriver40.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("androidPackage", "com.android.chrome");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.2gud.com/?cmpid=2G108229");
        Thread.sleep(3000);     
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/rv/viewcart']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Comment: I am using real device. Red mi note 5 pro. I am getting still same issue.

Comment: can u check code I added, it only uses selenium, it will auto pick device connected and listed by adb devices. please manage chromedriver.exe based on u r browser version.

Answer (score 0):

Try to click using mouse actions or JavaScript executor.

Comment: Please explain your answer with some examples. This looks more like a comment than the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code.

```
Xpath to find the view cart: //a[contains(@href,'viewcart')]
```

Executing a click via JavaScript has some behaviors of which you should be aware. If, for example, the code bound to the onclick event of your element invokes window.alert(), you may find your Selenium code hanging, depending on the implementation of the browser driver. That said, you can use the JavascriptExecutor class to do this. My solution differs from others proposed, however, in that you can still use the WebDriver methods for locating the elements.

```
// Assume driver is a valid WebDriver instance that has been properly instantiated elsewhere.
WebElement viewCart = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'viewcart')]"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", viewCart);
```

You should also note that you might be better off using the click() method of the WebElement interface, but disabling native events before instantiating your driver. This would accomplish the same goal (with the same potential limitations), but not force you to write and maintain your own JavaScript.